# How do I create Widget within plugin that uses its own class?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, oop

I wrote WordPress plugin and want to include 2 extra Widgets with it...

```
if( !class_exists('plugin_name') ) {
    class plugin_name {
            // plugin code
    }
}

// include widgets code
require_once( 'include/custom_functions.php' );
```

...and Widgets (according to WP codex) should be created like this within "custom_functions.php":

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    // widget code
}
function sfp_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sfp_register_widgets' );
```

I can't put "class SFP_Search extends WP_Widget" inside my plugin's class and if I place it outside, I get an error:

```
Class 'WP_Widget' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/...etc
```

Is there any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: could you explain what you mean? If you're putting one class inside another class, you can't do that in php

Comment: By default the class `WP_Widget` is loaded earlier than any plugin. Does your widget file run in a WordPress context, or do you call it directly?

Comment: @MridulAggarwal - I know I can't put one class into another, I'm trying to pack widgets along with a plugin.

Comment: Just put the widget class before/after your plugin's main class or in a seperate file & then include it in plugin's main file. It should work without a problem

Comment: @toscho - I have "my-plugin.php" that is main plugin file packed as a class. I'm trying to include additional file (require_once( 'include/custom_functions.php' );) that holds widget class and add_action. External file is included out of plugin class.

Comment: I have edit my question in order to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: On which hook do you include the class of your plugin? The best way is `plugins_loaded`. maybe you create a new instance via `new Your_Class` and this is to early for the class `WP_Widget`.

Comment: That's correct man, thanks a lot! It looks like WP_Widget is fired too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to nest classes (and you can't anyway), you just create a new instance of the class. The code below would automatically call the My_Widget class to create a widget based on your existing code.

```
Class plugin_name {
        // Call the widget class
        public function __construct(){
             $this->widget = new My_Widget();
             $this->widget->getWidget();
        }
}

Class My_Widget extends WP_Widget(){
     public function getWidget(){
          //Do my widget stuff.
          echo "I'm a widget";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are inside namespaced file, you should use slash in front of any global class:

```
class My_Widget extends \WP_Widget {
    ...
}
```